after upgrade to flutter 3.22 style problem for old libraries
i want to upgrade flutter version to 3.22
any trick to do that easily? without upgrade all libraries

Flutter 3.22 brings significant updates and fixes to the Material Design system, enhancing the user experience and providing developers with more tools and flexibility to create stunning applications.

because of this update all libraries that dosent updated for 1 year must be updated or changed manually to support new update changes
any fast fix?

The only way to solve this is to ask the publisher to make changes or you can fork the git repository and make changes as per your need and move to further usages.

ancient quote : "Don't use libraries. Real programmers write their own code." LOL

Lol harsh but truth but for now we can make our work easy by just forks.

It is because useMaterial3 flag is now turned to true by default. You can manually turn it to false in your ThemeData definition, and it should fix your issue. Note that this flag might be removed in a near future, so this "hack" probably won't work next time you'll upgrade your Flutter version, be prepared.

thanks for answer my question ... but i already set useMaterial3 to false in ThemeData but give me error in all libraries ... why flutter team ?? whyyyyy LOL

not only Android, I also have the same problem on Linux, this may be because they are impeller, I have created an issue on GitHub but they say it's fine, I don't know if this is my code's fault / their OS is outdated

even though my projects are up to date, they all use the latest libraries, I moved from flutter 3.19.6 to 3.22 then the UI error, but it doesn't throw
